# Change in Gemfile isn't reflected in Gemfile.lock

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, sqlite

I am suffering from the infamous SQLite3 Vs Heroku error while trying to deploy a simple Rails app.

Initially my `Gemfile` looked like

```
gem 'sqlite3'
...
```

After googling on the topic, I updated it to look like this:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
...
```

and then did a bundle install and surprisingly (at least for me),

```
$ git status --short 
M Gemfile
```

The `Gemfile.lock` did NOT change!

Now heroku keeps giving this SQLite error again and again because
the `Gemfile.lock` is same as before and bundle install keeps failing
on their server!

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Have you tried pushing your up to Heroku with updated `Gemfile`? If I understand it right, groups information is not represented in `Gemfile.lock`. Heroku is installing your gems with `--without development` option, so if I'm right about `Gemfile.lock`, then everything should be ok this time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Damn! It was a git issue.
I was working on a branch named 'deploy' and trying to push the 'master' branch and hence bundle install failed every time!

```
$git push heroku deploy:master
```

This made it work :)